# QGIS: Mergin two layers always creates new attibute field

Tags: qgis, layers, merge

I want to merge several layers into one. Each layer has a specific Attribute field (type: GG, DO, eg.). In the merged layer QGIS produced a new Attribute field for each type.

I want QGIS to but all the values in one Attribute field called "TYPE". All the values should be listed in that field.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do a postprocessing step and add a new field with the field calculator:

```
CONCAT( TYP, ',', TYP_2 )
```

then remove the old fields if you no longer need them.